# Retrieving new files from sharepoint to blob

Tags: azure, sharepoint, etl, azure-logic-apps

I am currenly working for a client that has a Sharepoint list in which every month, a new sub-map is made. Every day a new file is added to that month's sub-map.
I already designed a Logic App which copies all files to an Azure Storage Account, the problem is, I only need the most recent file. This is what the Logic App looks like:

[Logic App picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwMC6.png)

I tried to compare the Sharepoint-list with the blob storage list of yesterday so that every new day, a new file is recoqnized, but that didn't work out as i hoped.

Is there any way to retrieve only the most recently added files from a sharepoint list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *`filter array`* in **`compose`** Connector and compare *`LastModified`* with the specified time that you wanted i.e.. 24h, 12h

Here is the screenshot of the flow for your reference
[image]

And there by you can able to view all the blobs which are in timeframe of 24hours.

---

**Updated Answer**

If it is from Sharepoint then you can add Get files from Sharepoint connector and add filter array.

Here is the screenshot for your reference

[image]

In the image, I was referring to the list of 4 months value and could able to retrieve the same.

Comment: i tried your solution. I added a Filter array step and used the LastModified filter on the Sharepoint List Body as input. Unfortunately it still copies all of the files in the Sharepoint list. Could it be, that the Lastmodified is not recoqnized from a Sharepoint list?

Comment: @robin040 In that case add `Get files` from `Sharepoint` connector and add `filter array`. Here is the screenshot for your reference https://i.imgur.com/XSgVDid.png

Comment: @robin040 I have updated the answer. Please revert back if needed more assistance

Comment: @robin Did your issue got resolved?